# Split a string in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, split

I heard this forum is amazing for answering the craziest questions and I have searched hi and low for an answer to my crazy question, however I cannot find an answer. So I am putting this out to the community.

I use PowerShell for my scripting needs. please Don't offer me a solution in another scripting language, I'm sure other script languages will do this, however I need this in PowerShell.

I have many strings that I need to split they are similar in nature to:

```
HelloWorld
HelloWorldIAmNew
HelloWorldIAmNewToScripting
ThankYouForHelpingMe
```

I need to split them based on Capital Letters i.e.

```
Hello World
Hello World I Am New
Hello World I Am New To Scripting
Thank You For Helping Me
```

I have a basic understanding on splitting strings, but this is harder than your average string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fairly simple to do using a regex with negative and [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=pattern)` and the case-sensitive `-csplit` operator e.g.:

```
PS>  "HelloWorldIAmNewToScripting" -csplit "(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])"
Hello
World
I
Am
New
To
Scripting
```

Or if you want it space separated:

```
PS>  "$("HelloWorldIAmNewToScripting" -csplit "(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])")"
Hello World I Am New To Scripting
```

Comment: This add an empty line at start.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
("HelloWorldIAmNewToScripting" -creplace '[A-Z]', ' $&').Trim().Split($null)
Hello
World
I
Am
New
To
Scripting
```

or

```
("HelloWorldIAmNewToScripting" -creplace '[A-Z]', ' $&').Trim()
Hello World I Am New To Scripting
```